# Send --data-binary with file curl analogue in Java

Tags: java, http, curl, apache-httpclient-4.x

I would like to send POST request using Java equivalent of the following CURL example:

```
echo "param value" | curl --data-binary @-  -uuser:pass https://url
```

I've tried apache http setEntity(FileEntity entity), 400 bad request

I've tried apache http setEntity(MultiPartEntity entity), 400 bad request

```
// ----------------
// General part

String url = "https://url";
String content  = "param" + " " + "value";
File file = new File("test.txt");
try {
            FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, content, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

String encoding = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(("user:pass").getBytes());

DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
post.setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Basic " + encoding);

// -----------------
// 1. FileEntity try

FileEntity reqEntity = new FileEntity (file, ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY);
post.setEntity(reqEntity);

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(post);


// ----------------
// 2. Multipart try

MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file, org.apache.http.entity.ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY);
mpEntity.addPart("userfile", cbFile);
post.setEntity(mpEntity);

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(post);
```

I've expected to get 200, but got 400 Bad request.

Original CURL works as expected

Comment: Compare the requests, there should be an obvious difference. Also, don't write out to file just to read back in - simply use `String.getBytes`. My guess is text encoding woes - you're converting text to binary without specifying an encoding - especially in the curl case.

Comment: https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/org.apache.http.entity.ByteArrayEntity

Answer (score 0):

**Problem with  boundary parameter is not in the `Content-Type` header**

Actually If you are using one of `multipart/` content types, you are actually required to specify the boundary parameter in the `Content-Type` header ,But in here with curl request not trying generate any boundary values , without boundary values  the server (in the case of an `HTTP request`) will not be able to parse the payload